# Linking a Borland C Builder Package against a library

Tags: c++builder

I am currently performing maintenance on all kinds of obsolete applications created with Borland C Builder 6. A lot of these applications use a Package to interface to windows drivers. I can update the code of the .bpk easily by just minor changes to the source and linking in a `.a` or `lib` provided by a third party but it seems that the Package only supports code or `.bpi` libraries.  Any ideas how to link in the libraries into the package?

Comment: IIRC, you must add the libs manually using command line options (in the options settings). But that last time I used C++Builder **6** is ages ago, so I don't remember the details anymore. But I see you mention `.a` files. Did you perhaps mean **XE6**, which is only a few versions ago? C++Builder **6** did not support `.a` files. C++Builder **XE6** does. C++B 6 is from 2002, C++B XE6 is from 2014.

Comment: It is definitely C++Builder 6 from way back in 2002 (the project was started with C++Builder 5). There was no compelling reason to spend resource to update it until now. In C++Builder 6 there is no option for command line options. I was able to build it using a make file.

Comment: 2002 is a long time ago. I haven't used CB6 for ages. But IIRC, there was a way to add an option, somewhere. But if you managed using a make file, all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking in a Library can be done by selecting Project/Add to Project and adding the library than needs to be linked to the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this lines in a .cpp file in your package project.

```
#ifdef __MACH__
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib.a")
#endif
#ifdef __WIN32__
#pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib")
#endif
```

Comment: This is an option but I have always disliked defining linking in my code. To me this should go into a global project file not into some weird corner of the code. This is what BCB uses for components, when removing a component from  a from sometime you need to still remove the linking specification text that got orphaned.